# How do I block people with Empathy

Tags: 10.04, empathy

I'm trying to block a user from contacting me, but can't seem to do this from the Empathy interface. How do I block contacts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to version 11.10 (which included Empathy 3.0), this was not possible from the Empathy interface.

See also:

- [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/557521)
- [Upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=551911)
- [OMG! Ubuntu article regarding the new feature](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/empathy-3-0-adds-contact-blocking-finally)