# How to block contacts on Empathy?

Tags: 12.04, empathy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I block people with Empathy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4379/how-do-i-block-people-with-empathy)

I tried to block MSN contacts on Empathy through "Edit > Blocked contacts", but nothing happens. It's a bug? There is a way to block contacts?

Aditional info:

Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64

Empathy 3.4.1